# ¿Como puedo limitar una aplicación en Java a una sola instancia cuando lo arranco?

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo una **aplicación java** (`index.java`) que si la ejecuto navego por sus diferentes `JFrame` o `JDialog` sin problemas, etc.

Mi duda/pregunta/consulta es: ¿existe algún método para no permitir abrir durante el proceso de `index.java` otro `index.java`? Y en caso de intentar volver a abrirlo (si está abierto) mostrar un mensaje: "Está en uso".

Espero haberme explicado.

Código:

```
public class Index extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Index() {
        initComponents();
        //Fondo del JFrame en color gris.
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        //Código para confirmar el cierre de la ventana principal.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", "Salir de la aplicación",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Index().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No directamente del lado de java, si las instancias corren en dos maquinas virtuales distintos. Sin embargo puedes solucionar el tema con un archivo de bloqueo.

en el método *main* empiezas con:

```
// deberías definir la ruta de tu lockfile en una forma que siempre se guarda en el mismo lugar en el misma sistema
File lock = new File("ruta/a/mi/lockfile");
if (lock.createNewFile()){
    lock.deleteOnExit();
    //lanza tu applicación
} else {
    System.out.println("Está en uso.")
    System.exit();
}
```

Comment: Me gustaria dejarle esta informacion https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile() es muy posible que despues de leer la nota y el enlace a FileLock, quizas quiera mirar algun ejemplo de java.nio.channels.FileLock alomejor puede reajustar su respuesta. (si lo cree oportuno). Saludos

Comment: Esta solución me parece mejor que la del ServerSocket, con un socket solo puedes tener una instancia por cada PC, con archivos, puedes decidir q sea por usuario o por sesion.

Comment: Eso es independiente, con `ServerSocket` también se puede, solamente hay que usar un puerto por usuario/sesión, por ejemplo `5000+uid`

Comment: Si el proceso es terminado externamente mediante el SO o si se produce un error en tiempo de ejecucion el archivo no se eliminara y esto provocara que no puedas arrancar la aplicación

Comment: Eso es 100% correcto. Aun que `deleteOnExit()` es bastante confiable, obviamente un asesinato del proceso deja un archivo zombie, que hay que borrar manualmente. Existen un par de métodos de remediar eso, pero la mayoría son un poco más complicado porque no funcionan en la misma manera en cualquier SO.

Answer (score 3):

Una alternativa a simplemente evitar una segunda instancia de tu aplicación sería usar un `ServerSocket`para garantizar a un lado que no hay dos instancias corriendo y además pasar los argumentos de siguientes lanzamientos a la misma aplicación:

```
public class MiApp implements Runnable{

    public MiApp(){}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // código de la aplicación

    }

    public void nuevosParametros(String[] args){
        // aquí viene tu código que injecta otro juego de argumentos en tu applicación 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket serSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

            // uff, el puerto estaba libre, podemos hacer algo util... :)
            MiApp miApp = new MiApp();
            Thread t = new Thread(miApp);
            t.start();
            miApp.nuevosParametros(args);

            while(true){
                // aquí vamos a escuchar a lanzamientos de la aplicación
                // con distintos argumentos
                Socket sock = serSock.accept();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                Object o;
                try {
                    o = ois.readObject();
                    if (o instanceof String[])
                        miApp.nuevosParametros((String[]) o);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try{
                        sock.close();
                    } catch (IOException e){}
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // En el caso que puerto 5000 esta ocupado, resulta la IOException, entonces:
            try {
                // crea un Socket y envia los argumentos a la instancia corriendo
                Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(args);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code idea

```
RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile("C:/lock.class","rw");

FileChannel channel=randomFile.getChannel();

if(channel.tryLock()==null){ //no se puede adquirir el bloqueo, si esta bloquedado eso quiere decir que existe otro
System.out.println("existe una instancia");
```

---

No cuento con java ahora mismo pero pude encontrar el siguiente ejemplo en esta [pagina](http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/07/21/java-application-make-sure-only-singleone-instance-running-with-file-lock-ampampampampamp-shutdownhook/):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;

public class MyApp {

private static File f;
private static FileChannel channel;
private static FileLock lock;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    f = new File("RingOnRequest.lock");
    // Check if the lock exist
    if (f.exists()) {
    // if exist try to delete it
    f.delete();
  }
  // Try to get the lock
  channel = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw").getChannel();
  lock = channel.tryLock();
  if(lock == null)
  {
    // File is lock by other application
    channel.close();
    throw new RuntimeException("Only 1 instance of MyApp can run.");
  }
  // Add shutdown hook to release lock when application shutdown
  ShutdownHook shutdownHook = new ShutdownHook();
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);

  //Your application tasks here..
  System.out.println("Running");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not start process.", e);
  }
}

public static void unlockFile() {
// release and delete file lock
  try {
    if(lock != null)
    lock.release();
    channel.close();
    f.delete();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

static class ShutdownHook extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    unlockFile();
  }
}

}
```

---

El siguiente texto no es creado por mi puede visitar la funte [aqui](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/bloquear-un-fichero-con-java/)

> Lo primero que haremos para bloquear un fichero con Java será obtener
>   una referencia sobre el fichero mediante una clase File:
>
> `File file = new File("test.txt");` 
>   Para acceder al fichero vamos a
>   utilizar la clase RandomAccessFile en formato lectura y escritura. Y
>   sobre ese objeto vamos a recuperar su canal de acceso mediante el
>   método .getChannel().
>
> `FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();`
>
> Lo que manejamos en este momento es un objeto del tipo FileChannel. Un
>   canal en Java es la evolución de un Stream normal de datos. El caso
>   del FileChannel se representa una conexión abierta sobre un recurso
>   sobre la cual se pueden realizar múltiples operaciones. Una de las
>   operaciones que podemos realizar sobre el canal es bloquearlo o
>   liberarlo.
>
> Así, si queremos bloquear un fichero con Java, lo que hacemos es
>   bloquear el canal mediante el método .lock().
>
> `FileLock lock = channel.lock();` 
>   Lo que obtenemos en este caso es un
>   objeto FileLock. Este objeto será el que nos sirva para chequear el
>   estado del canal/fichero antes de acceder a él. Si queremos ver si el
>   fichero está bloqueado utilizamos el método tryLock() que devolverá
>   una excepción OverlappingFileLockException en el caso de que haya un
>   bloqueo.
>
> `try {   lock = channel.tryLock(); } catch`
>   `(OverlappingFileLockException e) {  }` 
>   También tenemos que saber que
>   para liberar el bloqueo del fichero tenemos el método .release()
>
> `lock.release();` 
>   Lo último que deberemos de hacer a la hora de bloquear
>   un fichero con Java es cerrar el canal sobre el fichero con el método
>   .close()
>
> `channel.close();` 
>   Con estas pequeñas líneas de código hemos podido
>   bloquear un fichero con Java..

ejemplo sobre un uso: http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:FileChannel.tryLock()

Comment: *creo pero no estoy seguro que con instrumente puede hacer algo similar*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

Aplicacion que creo lo usa ->

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-instance-application.html

Comment: Buen aporte, mejor despues de la edición.

Answer (score 0):

hola puedes hacerlo usando la libreria junique-1.0.4
La biblioteca JUnique se puede utilizar para evitar que un usuario ejecute al mismo tiempo más instancias de la misma aplicación Java. JUnique implementa bloqueos y canales de comunicación compartidos entre todas las instancias de JVM lanzadas por el mismo usuario. 
puedes buscar en Internet como usarla.